# Can you "fight" a coma or serious illness?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, medicine, injury

In an [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/19/world/americas/mexico-earthquake.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=a-lede-package-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news) about the latest earthquake to strike Mexico, I read that a rescuer said to someone in a gurney, "Fight for your life, please!"

I've seen similar things in TV shows and movies where a character is in a coma or seriously injured or ill.

But how much—if anything—can mentally "fighting" a coma, injury, or illness do?